# How to display current path in command prompt in linux's sh (not bash)?

Tags: linux, shell, sh, busybox

I would like to display current path in sh prompt (not bash shell), which currently just shows "#",
I tried with introducing this

```
env PS1="$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)"
```

and

```
set PS1="$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)"
```

in `/etc/profile`.

But as obvious this does not refresh when the the directory is changed or user changes.
Please suggest a way to make this dynamic.

Comment: Note that each `$()` runs a separate program; it would be faster to use environment variables, such as `$LOGNAME`, `$HOSTNAME` and `$PWD` instead.

Comment: One answer was to use single quotes instead of double quotes, however, that's quite the full correct answer.  What you really want to do is defer evaluation of the code inside your prompt until the prompt is used.

Comment: All  you need is to use export "PS1="$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd) >" then edit /etc/profile and append this line at the end.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Command substitutions in double quotes `"` get expanded immediately. That is not what you want for your prompt. Single quotes `'` will preserve the substitutions in `$PS1` which then get only expanded when displaying the prompt. Hence this should work:

```
PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)'
```

If you want the usual dollar sign and a space at the end of your prompt, simply add `$`  at the end (no escaping necessary): `PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)$ '`

Comment: Worked like a charm after changing 'set' to 'export' in your answer 


`export PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)$'` I saved the change s to `/etc/profile`. Thank you.

Comment: @Bleamer: `set` worked for me (but I didn't had a native `sh`). But I'll change it to `export` to comply with your setup.

Comment: Is there any way to make this permanent? Currently I have to do it each time I log in. Thanks!

Comment: You have put this line to `/etc/profile` (see question) or `~/.profile`?!

Comment: +1, this would need some delimiter at the end, though. As is, you get something like `foo@localhost:/home/fools -la` when using `ls -la`.

Comment: Yes, add this to /etc/profile for system-wide, or ~/.profile for a single user.   
All you need is to use export "PS1="$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd) $" then edit /etc/profile and append this line at the end.

Comment: Note that spawning the external `pwd` command is slow and not necessary. Using `\w` or `\W` or `${PWD}` would be much faster. Also, there is no point in exporting `PS1`. It should be set in your *~/.bashrc*.

Comment: @KurtisRader: The question is about `sh` and not `bash`, so `\w` isn't guaranteed to work. However, `export` is indeed not needed as I learned in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 16):

```
sh-4.2$ export PS1="\u@\h:\w>"
jenny@serenity:~>cd /usr/local
jenny@serenity:/usr/local>
```

Comment: I am afraid that works for bash shell not for sh, when i do this I get `\u@\h:\w>` as my command prompt

Comment: Must be a different sh version; as you can see from the first line, it worked for me in sh 4.2.

Comment: That may be the case. This shell is from Busy Box. Thank you. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Bleamer, it works for me with `BusyBox v1.19.4 built-in shell (ash)`.

Comment: Thank you for response @cjm, though I'll avoid digging further into this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it shows `~` instead of the full path. I doubt many people want to look at `/home/username/` or `/User/username/` all the time.

Answer (score 9):

This command works for me.

```
export PS1="\u@\h: \W:$"
```

Where 
*\u = username* 

*\h = hostname* 

*\W Name of present folder (not full path)*

Comment: +1 for \W parameter

Comment: My terminal keeps: `\W # ` from `PROMPT="%F{green}\W # %F{reset}"`. How fix?

Answer (score 7):

One might consider to pimp the prompt by adding some colors. For instance:

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;33m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\[\e[0;35m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\$ '
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I hope everyone like some colours in life :)

Comment: At least I do. ;)

Answer (score 2):

One answer was to use single quotes instead of double quotes, however, that's not quite the full correct answer.  What you really want to do is defer evaluation of the code inside your prompt until the prompt is used.

```
set PS1="$(pwd)"
```

sets the prompt to the working directory as of the set command.

```
set PS1="\$(pwd)"
```

does NOT expand $(pwd).  Instead, PS1 is set to the literal value of $(pwd).

Test / Understand this by running:

```
echo $PS1
```

.  If you see the string : $pwd, your prompt works.  If you see the literal path, the prompt is broken because it has been statically set

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below command to set is like in the cpanel.

export PS1='$(whoami)@${HOSTNAME%%.*} [$(pwd)]# '

Comment: Thanks! None of the other options above worked.  This one did. Was driving me crazy.  Thanks for saving my sanity. HA!

Answer (score 1):

Try this colorful MULTILINE prompt
Add this line

```sh
export PS1="[\e[1;33m\u\e[m@\e[1;36m\h\e[m] [\$(date +%k:%M:%S)]\n\e[0;32m[\w]\e[m \n\$ "
```

Prompt will be:

```
[yourusername@hostname] [17:34:13]
~   <----- this will be your working directory
>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. vim ~/.bashrc
2. add following lines:

```
# notice the tailing space
export PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)# '
```

3. open a new termal and you will find :

```
root@6e5efa720515:/opt/myapp#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the current branch and folder path in the terminal in Ubuntu using the following methods, assuming you are working with a Git repository:

1. Displaying Git Branch and Folder Path:

   To display the current Git branch and folder path, you can use the `git` command along with some shell commands. Here's a common approach to achieve this:

   Open your terminal and navigate to a directory within a Git repository. Then, add the following lines to your shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, depending on your shell):

   For Bash or Zsh:

```
    parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/\* /s///p'
    }

    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[31m\][\[\e[m\]\[\e[38;5;172m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[38;5;153m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[38;5;214m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[m\] \[\e[38;5;214m\]\W\[\e[m\]\[\e[31m\]]\[\e[m\]\\$ '
```

When you open new terminal it will look like this:

```
[root@chief main current-folder]$
```